Update records by matching with eachother within one table
I have the following table structure:

I want to match the records on the basis of transaction_ref and then update the ids of entry type records in invoice type records in column je_id
The result should look like this.

I tried the following but its not working:
UPDATE sales SET je_id = id WHERE type = 'invoice' AND transaction_ref = transaction_ref;


UPDATE..FROM results in an implicit JOIN. Give your target and source records an alias, then specify what needs to join to what.
In your case, targets are type='invoice', sources type='entry':
demo at db<>fiddle
update sales as t
   set je_id = s.id
from sales as s
where t.type='invoice'
  and s.type='entry'
  and t.transaction_ref = s.transaction_ref;




id
transaction_ref
type
amount
je_id




1
a
invoice
100
5


2
b
invoice
200
6


3
c
invoice
300
7


4
d
invoice
400
8


5
a
entry
10
null


6
b
entry
20
null


7
c
entry
30
null


8
d
entry
40
null



Quoting the UPDATE doc:

When a FROM clause is present, what essentially happens is that the target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the from_item list, and each output row of the join represents an update operation for the target table.

Further:

from_item
A table expression allowing columns from other tables to appear in the WHERE condition and update expressions. This uses the same syntax as the FROM clause of a SELECT statement; for example, an alias for the table name can be specified. Do not repeat the target table as a from_item unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the from_item).

And that's exactly what you need: repeat the target to get a self-join, give it an alias.
It's simple and it's fast.

With join:
UPDATE A
SET A.je_id = B.id 
FROM Table_1 AS A
INNER JOIN Table_1 AS B 
       ON B.transaction_ref = A.transaction_ref
       AND B.type = 'entry'
  where A.type='invoice'

Result:
id  transaction_ref type    amount  je_id
1   a           invoice     99  5
2   b           invoice     99  6
3   c           invoice     99  7
4   d           invoice     99  8
5   a           entry       99  NULL
6   b           entry       99  NULL
7   c           entry       99  NULL
8   d           entry       99  NULL


TOP 1 is SQL Server syntax

The JOIN clause executes before the WHERE clause. So, it’s better to limit data at the join level while updating the table.

@Hamza usman ghani: Sorry to say this, but this is nonsense. Dani's query is the proper way to write this. The condition A.type='invoice' does no belong in the ON clause, as it doesn't describe which B rows to join. For the DBMS it doesn't make a difference, but for human readers Dani's statement is appropriate, while your's is considered less readable.

@ThorstenKettner I disagree. This is the same mistake as Hamzausmanghani's: a double join. On top of that, this is trying to use a source's alias in the set section on the left, which is not allowed - you can't even use the target's name or alias there, only the target's column names, let alone trying to update some other tables records for whatever reason. It's also trying to re-use the target's name as an alias for one of the sources, without aliasing the target first to free the identifier. Demo

@Zegarek: Sorry about the misinformation. I am not a PostgreSQL developer, so I simply guessed that you could update with a join as shown. Glad, you clarified that. (Hamza usman ghani remark is still wrong :-)

@ThorstenKettner I don't think Hamza's idea is entirely wrong in that you should always try to filter as early as possible, aggregate before joining, etc. but Postgres rewrites queries anyways so it can move conditions around not just between the where and join..on sections but even push them down into subqueries, among other things. In this case, the change they suggested shouldn't matter at all. You're not wrong and it can be done this way - there's just no reason to, and you'd have to add a condition to avoid an effective join..on true with the target, which both Dani and Hamza forgot

Typically, you would get the IDs in a sub query:
UPDATE sales i
SET je_id = 
(
  SELECT e.id 
  FROM sales e
  WHERE e.type = 'entry'
  AND e.transaction_ref = i.transaction_ref
)
WHERE i.type = 'invoice';

This is a quite basic update statement and works in about every RDBMS.
As to your own statement: This cannot work. WHERE transaction_ref = transaction_ref is true for every row in the table of course, so you update every row. SET je_id = id updates a row's je_id with the row's id. This is not what you want.

In PostgreSQL, you can't use an alias on the left side of SET - only update target's columns are allowed there. Ironically, that excludes Postgres from the "about every RDBMS" group :) From the doc: "Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target column — for example, UPDATE table_name SET table_name.col = 1 is invalid." That being said, while rarely the first choice, the subquery method is perfectly valid.

I was hoping that maybe the index-only scan potential of this approach would help, but even with that, it doesn't look like it performs better than the standard update a..from a implicit self-join: demo

Thank you, @Zegarek, for adding all this information. I have removed the table qualifier from SET i.je_id to make the statement PostgreSQL compatible.

One option is to use Merge Into:
S a m p l e    D a t a :



id
transaction_ref
type
amount
je_id




1
a
invoice
100
null


2
b
invoice
200
null


3
c
invoice
300
null


4
d
invoice
400
null


5
a
entry
10
null


6
b
entry
20
null


7
c
entry
30
null


8
d
entry
40
null



--      S Q L :  
Merge Into sales s 
Using ( Select id, transaction_ref 
        From   sales
        Where  type = 'entry'
      ) x ON( x.transaction_ref = s.transaction_ref And
              s.type = 'invoice' And
              s.je_id Is Null)
When Matched Then Update
  SET je_id = x.id;

R e s u l t :



id
transaction_ref
type
amount
je_id




1
a
invoice
100
5


2
b
invoice
200
6


3
c
invoice
300
7


4
d
invoice
400
8


5
a
entry
10
null


6
b
entry
20
null


7
c
entry
30
null


8
d
entry
40
null



fiddle

Why? It reduces to merge into sales using sales..then update, so you can save some code and overhead by just running the update sales..from sales in the first place. Before v15 merge won't work at all, and before v17 it won't let you add a returning, so it also costs you some flexibility.

@Zegarek Sorry, but are you asking why this is an option. It just is an option. There may be some better and some worse ones, but, if they work then they are all options.that will or will not be accepted by OP. In my opinion it is better to know that you have more options than less.

I'm questioning the choice of this option, not its existence. My point here is it's not a different option - which I agree is always welcome - but rather that it's the same one, wrapped in more code, more problematic at that.

@Zegarek Arguably, the bigger the table Merge Into should be faster. You can check it  at https://dbfiddle.uk/_ArUEz-w

I don't see why you're handing my own demo back to me. Look: here's the same thing with only the seed changed - now merge is the slowest at 3.9s compared to Thorsten's and mine taking 3.6. That's because the difference at this point is down to noise since the three options get rewritten and optimised to pretty much the same plan. I'm not here to exchange fire, I'm genuinely asking for a reason you think wrapping the update in a a merge that seems to get immediately unwrapped an reduced away to the underlying update, would be a viable option.

@Zegarek Is there something wrong with the fiddle links - From your "here's the same thing link" ( https://dbfiddle.uk/Byg8aQWp ) the results, as they are shown to me, are: (cost/time) - Zegarek(10244/3599); - Thorsten(10248/3397) - dr(9707/3456)

@Zegarek The same from my link ( https://dbfiddle.uk/_ArUEz-w ) is (cost/time) - Zegarek: (10190/3777); - Thorsten: (10234/3509) - dr:(9782/3512)

Me copying and pasting them - maybe. If I enter what I claimed showed 3.6, 3.9, 3.6, I now see 3.6, 3.5, 3.4. Here, it's 3.7 for yours, 3.5 for ours - the first one typically gets penalised, so again: it's starting at noise.

Bumping up the size to about 40M rows and looping this test for a while shows the same thing: these start off taking about 4'40", and after a few loops stabilise hovering around 2'30". You can keep looping that and they'll keep switching places by a negligible amount.

@Zegarek So, the exec times are "noisy", but the cost is quite consistently in favour of Merge....

Cost is exec time. If you're referring to the plan cost in parentheses, it's the start-up/total time estimation, irrelevant if you're actually running the query and seeing it's way off the effective exec time throughout multiple tests. If you don't mind, I'm retracting my question here - pretend it was purely rhetorical and ignore the whole thing. Thanks for the time spent on responses.
